# QuerySet' object has no attribute 'save'

Tags: django

I'm getting this error when trying to get the image attribute
and set some values according to the content of `service_name` attribute,
both `service_name` and `image_url` are attributes of the same model,
but I want to set the image according to the content `service_name` using condition
statements. Any help or other way of doing it is highly appreciated

Here is the models module:

```
class JobServices(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    service_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, default="nom du service")
    hour = models.IntegerField(default="Heures")
    amount = models.FloatField(default="Cout")
    service_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, default="annonce")
    image_url = models.CharField(max_length=2000, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField()
```

And here is the view module

```
def taches(request):
taches = JobServices.objects.all()
if request.user.is_authenticated:
    service_name = request.POST.get('service_name')
    image_url = request.POST.get('image_url')
    if service_name == 'don du sang':
        image_url = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/4226902/pexels-photo-4226902.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'
        for object in taches:
            object.save()
    elif service_name == 'cours de soutien':
        image_url = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1181529/pexels-photo-1181529.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'
        for object in taches:
            object.save()
    elif service_name == 'jardinage':
        image_url  = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/4505166/pexels-photo-4505166.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'
        for object in taches:
            object.save()
    elif service_name == 'reparation':
        image_url = 'https://www.pexels.com/photo/gray-scale-photo-of-gears-159298/'
        for object in taches:
            object.save()
    else:
        image_url = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/8080823/pexels-photo-8080823.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500'
        for object in taches:
            object.save()
    return render(request, 'taches.html', {'taches': taches})
else:
    return redirect('login')
```

Taches.html:

```
div class="container">
<h2>{{ user }}, voici les tâches disponibles pour vous</h2>
<div class="row">
    {% for tache in taches %}
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ tache.image_url }}" alt="Card image cap">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title"><b></b>{{ tache.service_name }}</h5>
                    <b class="card-text"><b></b>{{ tache.amount }} VT pour {{ tache.hour }} heures  </b></p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Postuler</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Comment: `taches` is a `QuerySet` (a collection) of `JobServices`, not a `JobServices` object.

Comment: Pls don't give a model a plural name :) you are bound to confusing instances and querysets.

Comment: As a french myself your should not use french variable, task would be better and commonly understood, same for service name unless your market is French specific.

Comment: Alright. Noted, thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your queryset isn't a single object, you'll want to use the update method since you're dealing with multiple objects or a for loop.

[Updating multiple object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once)

or

```
for object in taches:
    object.image_url = 'URL'
    object.save()
```

In your template change :

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ tache.image_url }}" alt="Card image cap">
```

to

```
<img class="card-img-top" src="{{ tache.image_url.url }}" alt="Card image cap">
```

Comment: As you said I added the above for statement in each condition, the problem is gone but the images are uploaded, they are just missing. They are not rendered in the template

Comment: You did not pass the image_url object, see my updated answer and change it for every service_name

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still not getting the image rendered in the template. I uploaded the html page I rendered as you can see above

Comment: See my answer, you forgot the URL attribute for your image_url